# Disable ssh password authentication by user

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys

Is it possible to enable ssh password authentication for one user on a system and disable it for an other.

If you add

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
UsePAM no
```

to /etc/ssh/sshd_config you disable it for all users

Adding it to ~/.ssh/config doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a Match that matches all the users but the ones you want to be able to use password authentication and add the 'PasswordAuthentication no' in that Match block. Something like:

```
Match User someuser
PasswordAuthentication no
```

and so on.