# Allow password access for all users except root?

Tags: ssh, root, ssh-keys

I want to leave the root user enabled on my servers for convenience, and the only reason people are against the idea (that I know of) is brute-force attacks on SSH.

So, is there is a way in SSH to enable password access for all users except root, but allow ssh-key access for root?

**OS:** Ubuntu Server Edition 10.04 x86

**SSH Version:** OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable ssh password authentication by user](http://serverfault.com/questions/84199/disable-ssh-password-authentication-by-user)

Comment: This isn't exactly a duplicate, since there is a root-specific alternative.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the `sshd_config(5)` man page:

> ```
> PermitRootLogin
>           ...
>
>         If this option is set to “without-password”, password authentica-
>         tion is disabled for root.
> ```

Comment: Thank you!  I usually read the manual before asking, but this seemed sufficiently complicated enough not to be in the manual.  I was expecting some kind of iptables solutions, but this is better, obviously!

Comment: I would be kind of wary of putting `PermitRootLogin without-password` into my sshd configuration!